# Comparar tablas de dos base de datos y obtener datos a traves de un webservice

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual

Mi consulta es un poco generica.

Estoy creando un web service en C# para obtener datos de una base de datos "nube", compararlos con una base de datos "local", en caso de existir en local, no guardarlos; pero si no existe en local, pasar el dato de nube a local.

---

Edicion despues de los comentarios.

En mi program.cs tengo lo siguiente:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        if (args.Length > 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Inicio Villa");
            AccesoVA aces0 = new AccesoVA();
            aces0.inicia(args[0].ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("Proceso Terminado");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Inicio ");
            AccesoVA aces0 = new AccesoVA();
            aces0.inicia("");
            Console.WriteLine("Proceso Terminado");
        }
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

En mi AccesoVA, dentro de mi namespace, y dentro de una clase AccesoVa, tengo lo siguiente:

```
private string ExtraeCadenadeConexion()
{       
    string Cadena = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["VANube"].ToString();
    return Cadena;
}

public DataTable Conectar(string sql)
{
    try
    {
        SqlConnection cadena = new SqlConnection(ExtraeCadenadeConexion());
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, cadena);
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
        adapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
        cadena.Open();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        adapter.Fill(dt);
        cadena.Close();
        return dt;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //String script = "<script>alert('" + ex.Message + "')</script>";
        //System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(script);
        return null;
    }
}

public bool Inserta(string sql)
{
    bool resul = false;
    SqlConnection cadena = new SqlConnection(ExtraeCadenadeConexion());
    try
    {
        cadena.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = cadena.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = sql;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        resul = true;
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        resul = false;
        string era = ex.Message;
    }
    cadena.Close();
    return resul;
}

public void inicia(string dates)
{}
```

En mi void Inicia es donde empezare a construir todo para las comparaciones, para poder actualizar la base de datos "local".

Ambas bases de datos, las tengo en un SQL Server por el momento. Desconozco donde se hospedara a futuro la db "nube".

La db local es utilizada por una aplicacion, por lo que la web application sera para para en caso de contar con acceso a db "nube", poder copiar los datos a dblocal. Si los datos se encuentran en local y en nube, no hara nada, si se encuentra en local y no en nube, no hara nada.

Repito, soy un neofito en web service.

Comment: Y cual seria el problema?

Comment: Que seria base de datos "nube" ? usas Azure, AWS, etc. Que tipo de webservice? es un asmx, WCF, webapi con asp.net mvc, etc. Que es lo que has implementado hasta ahora? creaste el servicio y te retorna datos

Comment: ahorita ambas base de datos estan siendo manejadas desde un SQL server, los nombres solo son referencias a como se planea a largo plazo implementar. cree el servicio, tengo las conexiones, pero como mencione, es muy generica y de muy bajo nivel, no he logrado pensar como comparar ambas tablas por filas para en caso de que un registro exista en local, no agregarlo a la tabla. pero en caso de no existir en local, sustraer dicho dato de nube y agregarlo a local.

Comment: cual espera que sea la respuesta que brindemos? porque seria muy amplio si buscas que pongamos codigo para realizar todas las operaciones. Que partes tienes desarrrolladas? por ejemplo el web service con que tecnologia lo vas a desarrollar? como piensas marcar cada registro para saber si ya fue comparado? vas a compara todos los datos o solo algunos campos claves, no se si los id o code de ambas tablas nube y local coinciden. No evaluaste usar un servicio de replicacion estilo Sql Replication o Sync Service. La nube sera Azure? porque hay servicio de replicacion en este caso

Comment: soy un completo neofito realizando conexiones en sql server y manejando dichos datos.
el local no siempre contara con internet, el local cuando cuente con internet, se conectara a la nube. aclaro que por el momento tengo un total desconocimiento donde sera alojado dicha nube, por lo mientras tengo 2 base de datos iguales. SI la nube tiene nuevos datos que el local no tenga, debo poder copiarlos al local. si la nube no tiene nuevos datos para el local, no hara nada.
si el local tiene nuevos datos que la nube no tenga, no debe realizar nada. editare en mi consulta mas codigo, espero explicarme

Comment: cada registro tiene un id y un numero de folio unico, asi he intentado extraer los datos de una base de datos a otra. pero necesito revisar si ya existen en local para evitar jalarlos de nube, si existen en nube y no en local para traer el dato. y si existe en local pero no en nube no hacer nada.